# Bigtable - Cost of cross-continental replication

Tags: replication, google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to estimate the cost of Bigtable cross-continental replication.  It is not clear to me whether Bigtable replicates the entire row or just the changed data in "write" request. My guess it will only send the same write request to remote cluster like an event stream, but cannot confirm it with any documentation. This makes big difference in egress cost.  Does anyone have any experience?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bigtable only replicates the data being written, not the whole row, so your guess is correct.

Comment: This is valuable information for cost estimate.  It would be nice to see it in official document.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/pricing has this written down pretty well I think. "When you write to a cluster, Bigtable automatically replicates the write from that cluster (the "source cluster") to all of the other clusters in the instance (the "destination clusters"). If a destination cluster is in a different region than the source cluster, you are charged to replicate the write to the destination cluster. The charge is equal to the network egress rate to the destination cluster, multiplied by the amount of data that you wrote to the source cluster. "

Comment: Thanks, it is fair.  I was just not 100% sure when I read that.